# Setting Android TimePicker In XML

Tags: android, layout, timepicker

Is it possible to set TimePicker hours mode to 24-hours-mode in XML file? Or is it posible in Java only? I want to make a layout that has 24-hours picker but I can't find such attribute.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, you can't set the 24 hours mode in the XML, you have to use

```
MyTimePicker.setIs24HourView(boolean);
```

Answer (score 15):

It is possible by subclassing `TimePicker` to get a 24hour version, and using that sub class in the XML file with the appropriate package name:

```
public class TimePicker24Hours extends TimePicker {

    public TimePicker24Hours(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public TimePicker24Hours(Context context,
            AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TimePicker24Hours(Context context,
            AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setIs24HourView(true);
    }

}
```

in the layout you may add

```
   <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:dt_codecomponents="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/my.app.package"
    ...

      <my.app.package.style.TimePicker24Hours
            android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it from java file.

xml

```
 <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/timePicker" />
```

java

```
TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

timePicker.setIs24HourView(true); // to set 24 hours mode
timePicker.setIs24HourView(false); // to set 12 hours mode
```